# Wrong CSS location of Spark Application UI

Tags: apache-spark

I have Spark 2.1.1 standalone cluster running behind nginx proxy with the following relevant configurations:

On `spark-defaults.conf`

```
spark.ui.reverseProxy     true
spark.ui.reverseProxyUrl  http://<mydomain>/spark
```

On nginx site configuration

```
location /spark/ {
   proxy_pass http://spark-master:8080/;
   proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding '';
   sub_filter '/static/' '/spark/static/';
   sub_filter '/proxy/' '/spark/proxy/';
   sub_filter_once off;
}
```

When I access the pages of the application UI, for instance the following:

```
http://<my domain>/spark/proxy/app-20170831014128-0000/jobs/
```

They look very messy because their relevant CSS and Javascript files cannot be found as they are set to the wrong locations, for instance the following CSS file:

```
http://<my domain>/spark/proxy/app-20170831014128-0000/spark/static/bootstrap.min.css
```

I think it should be set to the following location:

```
http://<my domain>/spark/static/bootstrap.min.css
```

So at the moment, I worked around it by adding the `rewrite` directive on nginx as below:

```
location /spark/ {
   rewrite ^/spark/proxy/(.*)/spark/static/(.*) /spark/static/$2 last;
   proxy_pass http://spark-master:8080/;
   .
```

That is a quick and dirty work around. As I could not find any better solution so far after searching the internet, so I suspected perhaps there is something wrong on my setup.

Does anybody have suggestions where to look at? Or is this a known issue on Spark?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

On `spark-defaults.conf` add:

`spark.ui.proxyBase                 /spark`

And remove this on nginx site configuration:

`sub_filter '/static/' '/spark/static/';`

ref: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a2c7b2133cfee7fa9abfaa2bfbfb637155466783/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/UIUtils.scala#L150

EDIT:

Add my full config, it works for me on version 2.2.0.

`spark-defaults.conf` config:

```
spark.ui.proxyBase                 /sparkui
spark.ui.reverseProxy              true
spark.ui.reverseProxyUrl           https://<domain>/sparkui
```

nginx config:

```
location /sparkui/ {
    proxy_pass   http://<master>:8080/;
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding '';
    sub_filter '="/proxy/' '="/sparkui/proxy/';
    sub_filter_once off;
}
```

AND I found this PR https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/17455, it fixed reverse proxy path problem. this PR maybe merge to 2.3.0. Another way is https://github.com/aseigneurin/spark-ui-proxy, but I'm not try.

Comment: Thanks a lot eshizhan. I don't need the `rewrite` directive anymore after I applied your suggestion. I had actually searched for the usage of `APPLICATION_WEB_PROXY_BASE` or `spark.ui.proxyBase`, but I could not find any documentation mentioning about how to set it. I think I tried to set it to `http://<mydomain>/spark` but it didn't work so I removed it. I have only 6 points of reputation so I can not seem to cast my vote to say that your answer is useful.

Comment: The suggestion actually breaks other CSS location, e.g. the CSS files of the **Worker Id** URLs. That is due to the removal of `sub_filter '/static/' '/spark/static/';`on nginx config. But when I added that sub_filter again, it even breaks the main page as the same CSS of the main page becomes `http://<my domain>/spark/spark/static/bootstrap.min.css` (notice the double **spark**). I can workaround that with `rewrite` directive like `rewrite ^/static/(.*) /spark/static/$1 last;`, but it is very ugly as it has to be outside `location /spark/` which breaks other applications on the same domain.

Comment: Update my answer for add some research.

Answer (score 1):

My current solution is basically following the suggestion from eshizhan with some additional changes as below:

On `spark-defaults.conf`

```
spark.ui.reverseProxy     true
spark.ui.proxyBase        /spark
spark.ui.reverseProxyUrl  http://<my domain>
```

On nginx site config

```
location /spark/ {
   proxy_pass http://spark-master:8080/;
   proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding '';
   sub_filter '/proxy/' '/spark/proxy/';
   sub_filter '">Back to Master<' '/spark/">Back to Master<';
   sub_filter_once off;
}
```

It still look ugly as there seems to be no point to set the `spark.ui.reverseProxyUrl` and the hack on the **Back to Master** URL. But at least *almost all* URLs are now being properly rendered on my browser.

Does anybody have other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Although this thread is over 4 years old it did help me to figure out a solution because in Spark 3.1.1 you still can't serve the master UI + proxy the application ui's behind a reverse-proxy.

What worked for me (on compose demonstrated at least):

Configure following properties both both master, workers AND the applications.

```
spark.ui.proxyBase        /spark
spark.ui.reverseProxy     true
spark.ui.reverseProxyUrl  /spark
```

Notice reverseProxyUrl is a relative path; and as per documentation you need to configure the proxy for 3 documented responsibilities.

What works for me:

```
    location ~ ^(?<prefix>/spark)(?<local_path>/.*) {
        proxy_pass http://spark-master:8080;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";

        # Stripping the path prefix before forwarding the request
        rewrite ^ $local_path break;

        # Fix response header location
        proxy_redirect http://spark-master:8080 $prefix;
    }
```

Notice this is on compose (spark-master...), but the same should work on other setups.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

This is my fully functional solution with Spark version 3.5.0.

For your information, this is a mix of this SO thread solution and this tutorial https://8vi.cat/configure-nginx-as-reverse-proxy-for-sparkui/

In the nginx.conf

```
 location ~ ^(?<prefix>/spark-ui)(?<local_path>/.*) {
        proxy_pass http://<spark-master>:8080;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        # Fix response header location
        proxy_redirect http://<spark-master>:8080 $prefix;

        sub_filter '="/proxy/' '="/<spark-master>/proxy/';
        sub_filter 'href="/' 'href="/<spark-master>/';
        sub_filter 'src="/' 'src="/<spark-master>/';
        sub_filter_once off;
        sub_filter_types *;

        # strip prefix when forwarding request
        rewrite ^ $local_path break;

        # Stripping the path prefix before forwarding the request
        rewrite ^ $local_path break;
    }
```

In the `spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf`

````
spark.ui.reverseProxy     true
spark.ui.reverseProxyUrl  http://<domain>/spark-ui
```
````